# How to refresh the animated same view again in adapter android

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

On item click, adapter should refresh and onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder should be called again so the data and animation should be refreshed.

i want to animate recyclerview from right to left everytime the list is updated(whenever notifydatasetchanged is called) My list is getting updated but animation is not happening

```
 public myAdapter(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerview_songs){
   this.context = context;
   this.recyclerview_songs = recyclerview_songs;
 }


 @Override  
  public SongListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, 
 int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_songlist, parent, false);
      return new SongListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SongListViewHolder holder, 
final int position) {
  startAnimation(circle);
  if(!array_first.isEmpty()) {
      count =1;
      holder.text_name.setText(array_first.get(position).getTitle());
   }
 if(array_first.isEmpty() && array_second.size() > 0) {
      count =2;
      holder.text_name.setText(array_second.get(position).getTitle());
   }

holder.text_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          if(count ==1){
             array_first.clear();
             stopAnimation();
          }
          notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
  });
}

     public void startAnimation() {
    int animid = R.anim.animatefromright;
    LayoutAnimationController controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, animid);
    recyclerview_songs.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
}
```

Comment: How is your first animation happening? Any code to share?

Comment: Maybe you need to send the position of the item to reanimate the view.
And also calling startAnimation() method on onClick.

Comment: the list swipes in from right to left. So i cannot put the animation on a single position. And i updated the animation on click. @kvaruna

Comment: Can you also post the code for method startAnimation()

Comment: Updated the code. Please have a look @kvaruna

Comment: The method `startAnimation()` is triggering the animation so to start animation inside onclick write `startAnimation()` method rather than `stopAnimation()`

Comment: No i want to animate the recyclerview as soon as the adapter loads. First time it's happening from activity then second time when the whole adapter updates recyclerview list again swipes in from right to left with the different data. @kvaruna

Comment: Have you tried calling startAnimation() method from onClick? Or maybe am not getting your question correctly.

Comment: Yes i did, it's not working @kvaruna

Comment: My question is, i want to animate recyclerview from right to left everytime the list is updated. My list is getting updated but animation is not happening @kvaruna